# Merging both lists in C++ with merge

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, merge

I am having trouble with getting my two vectors to merge. They work rarely I get the a merged output. 90% of the time the program crashes. I'm new to C++ and to programming. The book i'm using is beginning C++ Game programming. Also using Microsoft visual C++ 2008.

here is my code.

```
//high scores
//demonstartes algorithms

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int>::const_iterator iter;
    cout << "creating a list  of scores.";
    vector <int> scores;
    scores.push_back(1500);
    scores.push_back(3500);
    scores.push_back(7500);


cout << "\nHight scores:\n";
for (iter = scores.begin(); iter != scores.end(); ++iter)
    cout << *iter << endl;

cout << "\nRandomizing scores.";
srand(time(0));
random_shuffle(scores.begin(), scores.end());
cout << "\nHighs scores:\n";
for (iter = scores.begin(); iter != scores.end(); ++iter)
    cout << *iter << endl;

cout << "\nCreating another list fo scores.";
vector<int> moreScores;
moreScores.push_back(2000);
moreScores.push_back(4000);
moreScores.push_back(8000);

cout << "\nMore High Scores:\n";
for (iter = moreScores.begin(); iter != moreScores.end(); ++iter)
    cout << *iter << endl;

cout << "\nMerging both lists.";
vector<int> allScores(6); //need container big enough to hold results
// allScores = null; //I tried to add a null statement to this so that memory would be clear. It didn't help.
merge(scores.begin(),scores.end(),
    moreScores.begin(),moreScores.end(),
    allScores.begin());


cout << "\nAll Hight Scores:\n";
for (iter = allScores.begin(); iter != allScores.end(); ++iter)
    cout << *iter << endl;

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The merge function is supposed to work with sorted arrays. The problem is when you shuffled your array with random_shuffle your array is likely to be not sorted (with probability 5/6 which is about 90%). Probably you caught a debug assertion which checks whether input is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) requires the ranges to be sorted. So you need to make sure the ranges are sorted first.

```
if (!std::is_sorted(scores.begin(), scores.end()))
  std::sort(scores.begin(), scores.end());

if (!std::is_sorted(moreScores.begin(), moreScores.end()))
  std::sort(moreScores.begin(), moreScores.end());

std::merge(scores.begin(),scores.end(),
           moreScores.begin(),moreScores.end(),
           allScores.begin());
```